# Problema no web.xml

Tags: jsp, netbeans, jstl

Olá!

Tenho meu meu web.xml, estou querendo colocar a dependência jstl, para isso estou usando o seguinte código:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Mas o Netbeans está mostrando a seguinte mensagem:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Foi detectado um conteúdo inválido começando
>   com o elemento 'dependency'. Era esperado um dos
>   '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":description,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":display-name,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":icon,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":distributable,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":context-param,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":filter,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":filter-mapping,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":listener,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":servlet,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":servlet-mapping,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":session-config,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":mime-mapping,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":welcome-file-list,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":error-page,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":jsp-config,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":security-constraint,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":login-config,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":security-role,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":env-entry,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":ejb-ref,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":ejb-local-ref,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":service-ref,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":resource-ref,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":resource-env-ref,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":message-destination-ref,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":persistence-context-ref,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":persistence-unit-ref,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":post-construct,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":pre-destroy,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":message-destination,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":locale-encoding-mapping-list}'.
>   [40]

Dizendo que o arquivo está inválido

Comment: Suas dependências devem ir no `pom.xml`, não no `web.xml`.

Comment: tenho que criar um arquivo chamado pom.xml?

Comment: Não uso o Netbeans, portanto não sei como é a estrutura dos arquivos de um projeto nele, mas se você criou um maven-project deve haver um `pom.xml` em algum lugar. Dê uma olhada [nesse guia](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-entapp_pt_BR.html) e veja se ele te ajuda.

Comment: nao criei um maven, ainda não estou nesse nível rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você não criou um projeto maven, você deve incluir o `JSTL` manualmente. Para isso, basta acessar o repositório do `JSTL` la no maven, escolher a versão e clickar em **Download JAR**.

[Repositório `JSTL` MAVEN.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl)

Em seguida, escolha a versão, a mais utilizada neste momento é a *1.2*.
[image: Passo 1 para adicionar JSTL manualmente.]

O próximo passo é baixar o *JSTL JAR*.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por fim, é só adicionar o JAR baixado la na pasta `lib` do seu projeto e linka-la através das propriedades do projeto.

*Botão direito em cima do projeto>Propriedades>Bibliotecas>Adicionar JAR/PASTA>Encontre o JSTL JAR*.

Pronto, você terá o `JSTL` adicionado ao seu projeto.

Agora basta utiliza-lo no `JSP` com a seguinte linha.

```
<%@taglib  prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Para você poder utilizar a *tag* `<dependency>` é preciso iniciar um projeto MAVEN.

- Veja como faz com o [ECLIPSE](https://cezarcruz.com.br/criando-um-projeto-maven-web-com-o-eclipse-jee/).
- Veja como faz com o [NETBEANS](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-entapp_pt_BR.html).

Comment: Será se era porque eu adicionava o jstl no servidor ao invés de eu utilizar na aplicação?